# Validation fails with iOS app with Watch kit extension in Xcode 12.3

Tags: watchkit, archive, ipa, xcode12

After archiving in Xcode 12.3 my archiving is getting  succeeded but while validating I am getting these two errors

**App Store Connect Operation Error Missing architecture. Apps built with Watch OS 5.0 and later SDKs must contain additional architectures.**

**App Store Connect Operation Error Invalid Code Signature Identifier. The identifier "com.apple.WK" in your code signature for
"AppName Watch " must match its Bundle Identifier "bundle
identifier"**